# How long is a WCF connection held open?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I'm running a small WCF client application that connects to an IIS server every few minutes to download data. There are about 500 of these clients for 2 or 3 servers, and my basic code is something like this:

```
Client connection = null;

try
{
    connection = new Client();
    List<TPointer> objects = connection.GetList();

    // Some work on List<T>

    foreach (TPointer pointer in objects)
    {
        T data = GetDataFromStream(pointer, connection);

        // Some additional processing on T
    }

    connection.SendMoreData();    

    // More work
}
catch (...)
{
    // Exception handling for various exceptions
}
finally
{
    // Handle Close() or Abort()
    if (connection != null)
        connection.Close();
}
```

When I simulate running all the clients at once for large amounts of TPointers, I start encountering the following error:

> System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00.

That seems like one of those errors that can occur for any number of reasons. For all I know the server could just be swamped, or I could be requesting too large/too many objects and it's taking too long to download (a whole minute though?). Increasing the timeout is an option, but I'd like to understand the actual problem instead of fixing the symptom.

**Given I have no control over the server, how can I streamline my client?**

1. I'm not actually sure what the "request channel" mentioned in the timeout refers to. Does the timeout start ticking from when I create new Client() until I call `Client.Close()`? Or does each specific request I'm sending to the server (e.g. `GetList` or `GetData`) get another minute? Is it worth my while to close `Client()` in between each call to the server? (I'm hoping not... that would be ugly)
2. Would it be helpful to chunk up the amount of data I'm receiving? The `GetList()` call can be quite large (running into the thousands). I could try obtaining a few objects at a time and jobbing off the post-processing for later...

**Edit:**

Since a few people mentioned streaming:

The `Client` binding uses `TransferMode.StreamedResponse`.
`GetDataFromStream()` uses a Stream derived from `TPointer`, and `SendMoreData()`'s payload size is more or less negligible.

Only `GetList()` actually returns a non-stream object, but I'm unclear as to whether or not that affects the method of transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a combination of the answers here, so I'll just post an answer. I chunked `GetList()` to a certain size to avoid keeping the connection open so long (it also had a positive effect on the code in general, since I was keeping less in memory temporarily.) I already have a retry policy in place, but will also plan on messing with the timeout, as The Anathema and a couple others suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> > Or does each specific request I'm sending to the server (e.g. GetList or GetData) get another minute?

The timeout property applies to each and every operation that you're doing. It's reset. If your timeout is one minute, then it starts the moment you invoke that method.

What I'd do is implement a retry policy and use an `async` version of the client's method and use a `CancellationToken` or call `Abort()` on your client when it's taking too long. Alternatively, you can increment or set your timeouts on the `InnerChannel` on the operation timout.

```
client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

You can use that during your operation and in your retry policy you can abort entirely and reset your timeout after your retries have failed or succeeded.

Alternatively, you can try to stream your results and see if you can operate individually on them, but I don't know if keeping that connection open will trip the timeout. You'll have to hold off on operating on your collection until you have everything.

Also, set `TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse` in your binding.

Comment: I'm actually already using StreamedResponse, though I failed to make it clear in the post. Have added more information. Would using StreamedResponse affect how List<TPointer> is transferred, though?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the timeout you are hitting is time to first response. In your scenario here first response is the whole response since you are returning the list, more data more time. You might want to consider streaming the data instead of returning a full list.

Comment: I'm using TransferMode.StreamedResponse; unsure if returning a list instead of a Stream object means I'm actually streaming that list, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to modify both your web.config file (wcf side) and also app.config (client side), adding binding section like this (i.e. timeout of 25 minutes in stead of 1 minute which is default value):

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IYourService"
             openTimeout="00:25:00" 
             closeTimeout="00:25:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:25:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:25:00">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Given I have no control over the server, how can I streamline my client?**

Basically you can not do this when you only have control over the client. It seems like the operations return no `Stream` (unless the pointers are types which derive from `Stream`).

If you want to know more about how to generally achieve streaming just read up on [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010(v=vs.110).aspx).

Everything you can do on the client is scratching on the surface of the problem. Like @The Anathema proposed in his answer you can create a retry logic and/or set the timeout to a higher value. But to eradicate the root of the problem you'd need to investigate the source of the service itself so that it can handle a higher amount of requests. Or have instances of the service running on multiple servers with a load balancer in front.